# Flatten Pandas DataFrame after read_json() with chunking on a very large file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a huge JSON file (~100GB) on my company's computer which I'm trying to load into a local database to automate some analysis on the data. To work around the memory constraints on the computer, I will need to read this file in batches into a pandas Dataframe, flatten the DataFrame similar to how json_normalize() does it, then put the flattened DataFrame into a queue where another thread will get it for inserting into the DB (e.g. QuestDB/InfluxDB).

If it was a small file, I would have gone ahead with json.load() followed by json_normalize(_),but json.load() doesn't support chunking, which then excludes me from using json_normalize(). Is there any other way I can flatten an existing DataFrame with nested JSON?

Sample Code:

```
import pandas as pd

def load_json(queue):
    filename = 'file.json'
    with pd.read_json(filename, lines=True, chunksize=2, orient='columns') as reader:        
        for df in reader:
            #perform transformation to flatten nested json columns
            queue.put(df)
```

Sample lines from file:

```
{"header":{"packetSize":8,"messageType":1,"clientCode":10000,"successFlag":0},"ReceiveTime":"2021-07-12T02:16:03.236"}
{"header":{"packetSize":98,"messageType":2,"seqNo":11111,"numRepeats":2,"timestamp":"07:46:03"},"data":[{"code":1,"high":0,"low":0,"open":0,"close":5238619,"value":5238619,"name":"ABC\u0000","time":"07:46:03"},{"code":2,"high":0,"low":0,"open":0,"close":1601565,"value":1601565,"name":"BAC100\u0000","time":"07:46:03"}],"ReceiveTime":"2021-07-12T02:16:03.717"}
{"header":{"packetSize":58,"messageType":3,"seqNo":22222,"numRepeats":1,"timestamp":"07:46:03"},"data":[{"code":47,"high":0,"low":0,"open":0,"close":1645846,"value":1645846,"name":"DEF50\u0000","time":"07:46:03"}],"ReceiveTime":"2021-07-12T02:16:03.741"}
{"header":{"packetSize":528,"messageType":4,"numRepeats":40},"data":[{"symbol":111111,"varRate":7500,"elmVarRate":350,"identifier":"E"},{"symbol":222222,"varRate":7500,"elmVarRate":350,"identifier":"E"},{"symbol":333333,"varRate":7500,"elmVarRate":350,"identifier":"E"},{"symbol":444444,"varRate":7500,"elmVarRate":350,"identifier":"E"},{"symbol":555555,"varRate":7500,"elmVarRate":350,"identifier":"E"},{"symbol":666666,"varRate":7500,"elmVarRate":350,"identifier":"E"},{"symbol":777777,"varRate":7500,"elmVarRate":350,"identifier":"E"},{"symbol":888888,"varRate":7500,"elmVarRate":350,"identifier":"E"},{"symbol":999999,"varRate":7500,"elmVarRate":350,"identifier":"E"},{"symbol":111222,"varRate":7500,"elmVarRate":350,"identifier":"E"},{"symbol":111333,"varRate":7500,"elmVarRate":350,"identifier":"E"},{"symbol":111444,"varRate":7500,"elmVarRate":350,"identifier":"E"},{"symbol":111555,"varRate":7500,"elmVarRate":350,"identifier":"E"},{"symbol":111666,"varRate":7500,"elmVarRate":350,"identifier":"E"},{"symbol":111777,"varRate":7500,"elmVarRate":350,"identifier":"E"},{"symbol":111888,"varRate":7500,"elmVarRate":350,"identifier":"E"},{"symbol":111999,"varRate":7500,"elmVarRate":350,"identifier":"E"},{"symbol":222111,"varRate":7500,"elmVarRate":350,"identifier":"E"},{"symbol":222333,"varRate":7500,"elmVarRate":350,"identifier":"E"},{"symbol":222444,"varRate":7500,"elmVarRate":350,"identifier":"E"},{"symbol":222555,"varRate":7500,"elmVarRate":350,"identifier":"E"},{"symbol":222666,"varRate":7500,"elmVarRate":350,"identifier":"E"},{"symbol":222777,"varRate":7500,"elmVarRate":350,"identifier":"E"},{"symbol":222888,"varRate":7500,"elmVarRate":350,"identifier":"E"},{"symbol":222999,"varRate":7500,"elmVarRate":350,"identifier":"E"},{"symbol":222000,"varRate":7500,"elmVarRate":350,"identifier":"E"},{"symbol":333111,"varRate":7500,"elmVarRate":350,"identifier":"E"},{"symbol":333222,"varRate":7500,"elmVarRate":350,"identifier":"E"},{"symbol":333444,"varRate":7500,"elmVarRate":350,"identifier":"E"},{"symbol":333555,"varRate":7500,"elmVarRate":350,"identifier":"E"},{"symbol":333666,"varRate":7500,"elmVarRate":350,"identifier":"E"},{"symbol":333777,"varRate":7500,"elmVarRate":350,"identifier":"E"},{"symbol":333888,"varRate":7500,"elmVarRate":350,"identifier":"E"},{"symbol":333999,"varRate":7500,"elmVarRate":350,"identifier":"E"},{"symbol":333000,"varRate":7500,"elmVarRate":350,"identifier":"E"},{"symbol":444111,"varRate":7500,"elmVarRate":350,"identifier":"E"},{"symbol":444222,"varRate":7500,"elmVarRate":350,"identifier":"E"},{"symbol":444333,"varRate":7500,"elmVarRate":350,"identifier":"E"},{"symbol":444555,"varRate":7500,"elmVarRate":350,"identifier":"E"},{"symbol":444666,"varRate":7500,"elmVarRate":350,"identifier":"E"}],"ReceiveTime":"2021-07-12T02:16:04.545"}
```

Comment: Do you need to use the dataframe at all? What about reading the file line by line and constructing the appropriate insert directive yourself?

Comment: that could be an option, although I'd like to see if this method yields better performance since I can read large chunks of lines at one go for inserting into the DB, and hopefully apply transformation more easily as well.